# Strange Startup Error Messages

Tags: warning-messages

Seemingly out of nowhere when I open Mathematica a messages window pops up with these two warnings. This issue starting occurring after no changes where made.

```
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in $Failed<>/Persistence.

LocalObject::uri: Persistence is not a valid Local Object URL.
```

Additionally, when I run `wolframscript` I get a slightly longer message

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open URLUtilitiesLoader`.

LocalObject::uri: Persistence is not a valid Local Object URL.

PersistenceLocation::invalid:
   Persistence location PersistenceLocation[Local, $Failed, ReadOnly -> True]
     is not valid.

PersistenceLocation::invalid:
   Persistence location PersistenceLocation[Installation, {$Failed}]
     is not valid.

PersistenceLocation::invalid: Persistence location $Failed is not valid.

General::stop: Further output of PersistenceLocation::invalid
     will be suppressed during this calculation.

PersistenceLocation::ploc:
   StartUp`Initialization`$BootstrapPath is not a persistence location.

PersistenceLocation::fe:
   No FrontEnd available; FrontEnd persistence location is not supported.

LocalObject::lbx:
   Cannot set $DefaultLocalBase to /Users/tomginsberg/Library/Wolfram/Objects.

StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in $Failed<>/Persistence.

LocalObject::uri: Persistence is not a valid Local Object URL.
```

Really not sure why this started happening any insight would be helpful, thx.

Comment: Try [resetting Mathematica to its default configuration](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) Beware, You will need to activate your license again. This are the folders to delete `{
 $BaseDirectory,
 $UserBaseDirectory,
 $LocalBase,
 $CacheBaseDirectory
}`

Comment: @rhermans Thanks that fixed everything

Answer (score 2):

Fixed following steps from @rhermans

1) Delete directories `$BaseDirectory, $UserBaseDirectory, $LocalBase, $CacheBaseDirectory`

2) Re-activate Mathematica